# How to maintain login session across multiple apps using AirWatch on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, airwatch

I have multiple enterprise applications installed on my device and applications are configured with AirWatch SDK. All applications require login authentication. User can login into every application with same credential.

I want to maintain the login session across all application. Is there any possibility to do it using AirWatch SDK?

Comment: I think you need the AirWatch Container to have SSO on your devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AirWatch SDK has the capability of what they call single sign on. This feature allows all of your AirWatch SDK enabled application to maintain a single log in session on one device.

This functionality is NOT controlled via code by using any API but you have to select sso option in the SDK profile that is pushed along with your app from the AirWatch MDM console.